# Multiple Subplots with (Sub-)Subplots (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, plot

I aim to create 14 subplots with four figures in each subplot. Unfortunately, I do not have any example code to show, as I have not a clue how to go about this. A couple ideas that have popped into my head about how I can go about accomplishing this. One is to create multiple figures separately, then merge them into a single figure. Another is to create subplots with multiple subplots nested inside of them; however, again, I have not a clue how I could go about accomplishing this.

Comment: Can you create a box figure in paint or something? I've done something similar but not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: 14 subplots x4 plots each? I think that 56 plots in a single figure is going against the purpose: showing the results. Just make 14 figures with 4 subplots each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find that you are trying to fit too much data onto one figure, and the plots will be too small to see anything of interest.  However, a techniques that works, and will give you the option of having individual figures, and combining them into one figure if you wish, is to use individual figures each with a panel on it, then use `copyobj` to copy to your main figure.

For example,

```
% Create first figure
hf_sub(1) = figure(1);
hp(1) = uipanel('Parent',hf_sub(1),'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
subplot(2,2,1,'Parent',hp(1));
plot(1:10);
subplot(2,2,2,'Parent',hp(1));
surf(peaks);
subplot(2,2,3,'Parent',hp(1));
membrane;
subplot(2,2,4,'Parent',hp(1));
plot(rand(1,100));

% Create second figure
hf_sub(2) = figure(2);
hp(2) = uipanel('Parent',hf_sub(2),'Position',[0 0 1 1]);
subplot(2,2,1,'Parent',hp(2));
histogram(randn(1,1000));
subplot(2,2,2,'Parent',hp(2));
membrane
subplot(2,2,3,'Parent',hp(2));
surf(peaks)
subplot(2,2,4,'Parent',hp(2));
plot(-(1:10));

% Create combined figure
hf_main = figure(3);
npanels = numel(hp);
hp_sub = nan(1,npanels);
% Copy over the panels
for idx = 1:npanels
    hp_sub(idx) = copyobj(hp(idx),hf_main);
    set(hp_sub(idx),'Position',[(idx-1)/npanels,0,1/npanels,1]);
end
```

You may need to be more careful with positioning of the panels, and may want to create the individual figure with their visibility set to `off`, but the above gives the main idea.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for - it works wonderfully with my code. Thank you!